# BeginInvoke is locking UI

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, asynchronous, begininvoke

I'm developing one application that displays images from one sensor.
For this I'm using BeginInvoke on the Main UI.

```
private void cameraCtrller_ImageProcessed(object sender, ImageProcessedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myDisplay.InvokeRequired)
    {
        myDisplay.BeginInvoke(
            new EventHandler<ImageProcessedEventArgs>(cameraCtrller_ImageProcessed),
            sender,
            e
        );
    }
    else
    {
        myDisplay.DrawImage(e.Image);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the images are coming fast and the UI after some time (sporadically) gets unresponsive. Sensor is always faster than the UI..

While the UI is unresponsive, if I set a breakpoint at the BeginInvoke it breaks, but it never reaches the DrawImage.

Having this, I tried to execute `Application.DoEvents();` after the break in the BeginInvoke and it started reaching DrawImage, but it is not a good solution to leave this at each image received.

Any ideas of how to solve this? any possibility to discard images that the UI cannot present?

Comment: have you tried using directly `Invoke(..)` ? BeginInvoke is not executed (as far as I know) directly but can be delayed. This way you probably get overlapping drawing attempts

Comment: It's possible that you have overflowed the Windows Message Queue (which by default has a limit of 10,000 items). If this happens, the `BeginInvoke()` will fail to post its message in the queue, and will therefore have no effect.

Comment: it is normal. Do it under Task.

Comment: Don't create an event handler each time the event itself is called. Try `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => myDisplay.DrawImage(e.Image));`, removing everything else. If you're setting a PictureBox.Image or using a Bitmap, dispose of the previous Image or Bitmap each time berfore you assign/draw on another one.

Comment: @MongZhu I had Invoke, but decided to change to BeginInvoke, the issue was appearing on both.

Comment: @Jimi I don't have memory issues, I think having the event handler will only assign one more Eventargs, the speed and stack will still be an issue, correct? Either way I'll make a test ;)

Comment: Note that, in WinForms, it's improbable to generate a frame rate > 30~32 fps.